# Cannot install pyttsx3

Tags: python, installation, grammar, pyttsx, nosuchfileexception

Using python.exe, I have trouble installing **pyttsx3** in **python 3.5**. I get the following error:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main (['install','pyttsx3'])
Collecting pyttsx3
 Downloading pyttsx3-2.6.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

D:\Stuff\Python\python35.zip\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'summary'
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Stuff\\Python\\python35.zip\\lib2to3\\Grammar.txt'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\carriedr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-0ke80vwe\pyttsx3\
1
```

## I have tried:

- multiple other sites
- unzipping a copy of python35
- running grammar.txt under python and pythonw.

Comment: This error is common when you don't have the module "setuptools" installed. So try "pip install --upgrade setuptools"

Comment: you're trying to run the command `pip install pysttx3` from inside a python console. That's not how you install packages. Open a normal terminal and run `pip install pysttx3` there.

Comment: @HakRo I tried upgrading setuptools, but the code window closed on me.

Comment: thank you @GPhilo, I did that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the shell, it works now, it couldn't find the file though because of my file path.